# Having trouble comparing index of a list to a string

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, string-comparison

So I have a string list, which looks somthing like this-

```
..A...C..C.
.....A.....
```

And I'm basically trying to check if at a certain index there is a "." or a letter.  However. whenever I try something like

```
if(array[row][column] == ".")
{
  return true;
}
```

I get an error saying I can't compare pointers and integers (which I suppose is because the list is a pointer, but is the "." an integer..?)
I've tried converting the array index to string but when it compares, it always comes back false.

Comment: What is type of `array`? You may want `array[row][column] == '.'` (single quotation marks instead of double) instead.

Comment: Converting array *element* instead of array *index* to string should also work: `std::string(1, array[row][column]) == "."`

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for:

```
if(array[row][column] == '.')
```

If you want to compare the array element to a `char`, you need to use `'` instead of `"`.

The error about comparing pointers and integers comes from the fact that `"."` is a string literal with the type `const char [2]` which decays to a `const char*`, and the `array[row][column]` is a single `char` which is treated like an integer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't *need* to use `'` because you can access elements of the array like `if(array[row][column] == "."[0])` (using `'` is easier, simpler, and usual way though)

Comment: Changing that to a character instead of string worked perfectly, thanks!